# A Web Application, multiple Site Collections and multiples databases

Tags: site-collection, database

It's possible have a Web Application with many Site Collections and multiple databases?

One database per Site Collection?

All this in a existing SharePoint 2013

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

- You can have multiple databases attach to a web application(500 is
  limit).
- You can have the many site collections and provision one site
  collection into one content DB.

Read more about the limits here.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#ContentDB

Comment: How I assign a site collection with a database and other site collection in the same web application to other database?

Comment: If you are usning powershell to create new site collection then their is one parameter called "ContentDatabase" wher eyou specify the db name.https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607937(v=office.15).aspx